# Add columns to WooCommerce Reports / Order List

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add extra data in the Woo-Commerce report for Orders. I want to add two custom user field and product type column in the report so that one can download the CSV with the newly added data.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED YET**

While researching for the issue, I found this [article](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2020/02/20/extending-wc-admin-reports/) by Woo-Commerce developers. While going through this article I was able to add custom columns in my orders report but I am unsure on how do I push data to `reportTableData` variable which would eventually be reflected on the table.

My code to add column in order report of woocommerce is:

```
const addTableColumn = reportTableData => {
    if ('orders' !== reportTableData.endpoint) {
        return reportTableData;
    }

    const newHeaders = [{
            label: 'Currency',
            key: 'currency',
        },
        ...reportTableData.headers,
    ];
    const newRows = reportTableData.rows.map((row, index) => {
        const item = reportTableData.items.data[index];
        console.log(item);
        const newRow = [{
                display: item.currency,
                value: item.currency,
            },
            ...row,
        ];
        return newRow;
    });

    reportTableData.headers = newHeaders;
    reportTableData.rows = newRows;

    return reportTableData;
};

addFilter('woocommerce_admin_report_table', 'dev-blog-example', addTableColumn);
```

I have copied this from the article and this code ads Currency column in the report table. I can add more column by adding item in `newHeader`.

I am unsure on how to get the data available, which I can use to map the data inside the row.

**UPDATE #1**
Console log of items is :

```
​
_links: Object { order: (1) […] }
customer_id: 1
customer_type: "new"
date_created: "2020-06-24 12:05:58"
date_created_gmt: "2020-06-24 12:05:58"
extended_info: Object { products: (1) […], coupons: (1) […], customer: {…} }
net_total: 0
num_items_sold: 1
order_id: 51
order_number: 51
parent_id: 0
status: "processing"
total_sales: 0
```